# Extract pdf text at specific location from each page of document using NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, extract, pdf-parsing

I have pdf document that will have multiple pages in it. Each page will have unique ID in footer. My job is to separate each page in document into separate pdf file and save it, using ID  ( "invoice_{ID}" )  in filename, using **NodeJS**.

Here is basic document structure :

```
document
   page1
     footer1 ( unique_id1 located here)
   page2
      footer2 (unique_id2 )
   ...
   pageN
      footerN
```

I was able to separate document into smaller pdfs and save it using this code ( found on stackoverflow) :

```
// split.pdf.js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { PDFDocument } = require('pdf-lib');



const splitPDF = async (pdfFilePath, outputDirectory) => {
  const data = await fs.promises.readFile(pdfFilePath);

  const readPdfText = await pdfParser(data);
  const readPdf = await PDFDocument.load(data);
  const { length } = readPdf.getPages();

  for (let i = 0, n = length; i < n; i += 1) {
    const writePdf = await PDFDocument.create();
    const [page] = await writePdf.copyPages(readPdf, [i]);
    writePdf.addPage(page);
    const bytes = await writePdf.save();
    const outputPath = path.join(outputDirectory, `Invoice_Page_${i + 1}.pdf`);
    await fs.promises.writeFile(outputPath, bytes);
    console.log(`Added ${outputPath}`);
  }

};

splitPDF('./invoices.pdf', 'splitted').then(() =>
  console.log('All invoices have been split!')
).catch(console.error)
```

Now, how can I extract that unique_id from each footer and use it in filename when I save new file?

My second issue is that whatever solution comes in place it has to work 100% correctly because each file will have confidential information and I really can't screw it up lol :)
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

if you have them split already you could possibly use "pdf-parse" NPM library and do a search/find on the data.text returned

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-parse

Comment: Thank you! I'll check that out. Seems like a solution